# Not refreshing after setting cookie

Tags: javascript, cookies, refresh

Can I have some help please? Using Javascript, I am setting a cookie, then refreshing the page. My currently broken code:

```
var username=getCookie("username");
if (username!=null && username!="")
{
    document.write("Welcome, " + username + "! <br/> <input type='button' value='Click to reset your name!' onclick='setCookie(\"username\",\"\",-1);' onmouseup='window.location.reload(true);'/>");
}
else
{
    username=prompt("Please enter your name:","Nothing is stored on the server.");
    if (username!=null && username!="")
    {
        setCookie("username",username,365);
    }
    window.location.reload(true);
}
```

Get cookie:

```
function getCookie(c_name)
{
var i,x,y,ARRcookies=document.cookie.split(";");
for (i=0;i<ARRcookies.length;i++)
  {
  x=ARRcookies[i].substr(0,ARRcookies[i].indexOf("="));
  y=ARRcookies[i].substr(ARRcookies[i].indexOf("=")+1);
  x=x.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,"");
  if (x==c_name)
    {
    return unescape(y);
    }
  }
}
```

The problem is the in the else{} part of the first part of the code. Thanks in advance! :)
I apologize if my code or it's formatting is incorrect. :(

Comment: Just formatted your code. Please edit your post to learn how to do so in the future.

Comment: Is it me, or did you just clone http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp?

Comment: I am using it for my code, yes. But I am trying to refresh automatically, which is what this post is for.

Answer (score 0):

Please can we see the definition of getCookie? What does it return if the cookie isn't set?

Have you looked at the JS error console?

Code reformatted below.

```
var username=getCookie("username");
if (username!=null && username!="")
{
    document.write("Welcome, " + username + "! <br/>
                    <input type='button' value='Click to reset your name!'             
                        onclick='setCookie(\"username\",\"\",-1);'
                        onmouseup='window.location.reload(true);'/>");
}
else
{
    username=prompt("Please enter your name:","Nothing is stored on the server.");
    if (username!=null && username!="")
    {
        setCookie("username",username,365);
    }
    window.location.reload(true);
}
// This last } is superfluous and may indicate issues with brackets
}
```

Comment: I have included getCookie in the main post.